# Blink no fundo e na cor do texto

Tags: jquery

Fala pessoal, estou com o seguinte código para fazer um efeito blink em uma div, estou conseguindo mudar a cor do fundo da div de meio em meio segundo, porém preciso modificar a cor do texto e não estou conseguindo encontrar a logica para essa mudança.

Segue o exemplo do código atual

```
setInterval(function () {
    $(".laranja").css("background-color", function () {
        this.switch = !this.switch
        return this.switch ? "rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3)" : ""
    });
}, 500)
```

Tentei fazer assim e deu certo

```
setInterval(function () {
        
        $(".laranja").css("background-color", function () {
            this.switch = !this.switch
            return this.switch ? "rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3)" : ""
        });
        
        $(".laranja").css("color", function () {
            this.color = !this.color
            return this.color ? "#FFF" : ""
        });
        
        
    }, 500)
```

Mais não sei se é a forma mais clean e certa de fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tambem não sei se e a melhor maneira porem eu faria desse modo :

```
setInterval(function (){$(".laranja").css({function (){ 
    this.switch = !this.switch;
    this.color = !this.color;
    //Definir a cor do background
    bg=this.switch ?'black':''; 
    //Definir a cor do texto
    cor=this.color ?'#fff':'';  
    $(".laranja").css({backgroundColor:bg,color:cor});
}    
})},500);
```

```js
setInterval(function (){$(".laranja").css({function (){ 
        this.switch = !this.switch;
        this.color = !this.color;
        //Definir a cor do background
        bg=this.switch ?'black':''; 
        //Definir a cor do texto
        cor=this.color ?'#fff':'';  
        $(".laranja").css({backgroundColor:bg,color:cor});
    }    
    })},500);
```

```html
<div class="laranja">abc</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Vou usar a sua versão, me parece ser mais leve que a minha rs